# React UseState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am trying to change the state of the product quantities whenever someone clicks on a button (Increment/decrement). But somehow it is not incrementing the quantity here.
When I click on increment button, it changes the quantity for the first item. When I click on second item increment button, it reset the quantity for first item and make changes to the second one.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fifeQ.png

Here's my `code`

```
**App.js**

function App() {

let [productList, setProductList] = useState([]);

productList = [
{
      id: 0,
      prodName: "iPhone X",
      type: "Mobile",
      price: "80000",
      quantity: 0,
},
{
      id: 1,
      prodName: "iPhone 11",
      type: "Mobile",
      price: "120000",
      quantity: 0,
},
{
      id: 2,
      prodName: "iPhone 12",
      type: "Mobile",
      price: "180000",
      quantity: 0,

}];

const incrementQuantity = (index) => {
    let newProductList = [...productList];
    newProductList[index].quantity++;
    setProductList(newProductList);
    console.log(newProductList); 
}
return (
    <div className="App">
      
      <Header heading="Simple Cart project" />
      <Mediator list={productList} incrementQuantity={incrementQuantity} />
      {/* list is the property name which you are passing to different component */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
    

**Mediator.js**
    
function Mediator(props) {
    return (
            props.list.map((product, index) => {

                return <ProductList productList={product} key={index} incrementQuantity = {props.incrementQuantity} index={index}/>
            })
    );
}
export default Mediator;
    
    
**ProductList.js**
    
function ProductList(props) {
    console.log("inside product list")
    console.log(props);

    return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-5">
                <h2>{props.productList.prodName} </h2> <span className="price-column"><Chip label={props.productList.price} color="success" />₹ <br />
                </span> <br />
            </div>
            <div className="col-3">
                <ButtonGroup size="small" color="secondary" aria-label="small button group">
                    <Button className="btn-decrease">-</Button>
                   
                    <Box
                        component="div"
                        sx={{
                            display: 'inline',
                            p: 1,
                            m: 1,
                            bgcolor: 'background.paper',
}}
                    >
                        {props.productList.quantity}
                    </Box>

                    <Button className="btn-increase"
                        onClick={() => { props.incrementQuantity(props.index) }}

                    >+</Button>
                </ButtonGroup>
            </div>
            <div className="col-4">
                <span><h4>Total Cart Price: </h4>{props.productList.quantity * props.productList.price}</span>
            </div>
        </div>

    );
}

export default ProductList;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because on every render the very first thing you do is locally modify the variable holding the state to a hard-coded list of initial values.  Don't mutate state like that.

Instead, set that hard-coded initial value as the initial default for the `useState` hook:

```
let [productList, setProductList] = useState([
{
      id: 0,
      prodName: "iPhone X",
      type: "Mobile",
      price: "80000",
      quantity: 0,
},
{
      id: 1,
      prodName: "iPhone 11",
      type: "Mobile",
      price: "120000",
      quantity: 0,
},
{
      id: 2,
      prodName: "iPhone 12",
      type: "Mobile",
      price: "180000",
      quantity: 0,

}]);
```

Never directly modify or replace `productList`, only use `setProductList` to update it.

Answer (score 0):

[David's answer is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70592850/2458149) but there's another problem with your code in that you need to get the previous `productList` state in your `setProductList` if you want to modify `productList` to be safe in case anything else (like a different `incrementQuantity` call) has modified it.

```
function App() {

  const [productList, setProductList] = useState([
    {
      id: 0,
      prodName: "iPhone X",
      type: "Mobile",
      price: "80000",
      quantity: 0,
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      prodName: "iPhone 11",
      type: "Mobile",
      price: "120000",
      quantity: 0,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      prodName: "iPhone 12",
      type: "Mobile",
      price: "180000",
      quantity: 0,

    }]);

  const incrementQuantity = (index) => {
    setProductList((prodList) => {
      prodList[index].quantity++;
      return prodList;
    });
  }
  
  ...
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you be cloning the `prodList` and then incrementing the quantity on that cloned `prodList` rather than directly mutating the state?

Comment: Thank you so much @David and I'm Joe Too. Now the code is working fine. :)
And I am agree with Sangeet Agarwal too. We should clone the productList first instead of directly making the changes in the initial values!